Is it possible to connect Gazebo simulation to physical model?
I am trying to create a SCARA robot. The physical setup is ready. What I want to do is create a setup such that the movements in the gazebo simulation are reflected in the actual physical robot. I have seen that it is possible in rviz, but wanted to know if it's possible in gazebo, and if yes then how?

Many years ago, I made an experiment using a motion capture system (Vicon) to get the location and pose of a stick. I recorded this pose with the Vicon system and used it to modify the pose of a stick object in Gazebo. I made a small C++ plugin for Gazebo to create the connection.
Here is my code if it can help: GitHub repo
You are obviously not asking about a motion capture system, but in your case, you are probably able to read the joint angles. You can then send them into Gazebo using the plugin. You need to have made a model of your robot in Gazebo.
